# Contents of elasticsearch snapshot

Tags: elasticsearch

We are going to be using the snapshot API for blue green deployment of our cluster. We want to snapshot the existing cluster, spin up a new cluster, restore the data from the snapshot. We also need to apply any changes to the existing cluster data to our new cluster (before we switchover and make the new cluster live).

The thinking is we can index data from our database that has changes after the timestamp of when the snapshot was created, to ensure that any writes that happened to the running live cluster will get applied to the new cluster (the new cluster only has the data restored from the snapshot). My question is what timestamp date to use? Snapshot API has start_time and end_time values for a given snapshot - but I am not certain that end_time in this context means “all data modified up to this point”. I feel like it is just a marker to tell you how long the operation took. I may be wrong.

Does anyone know how to find what a snapshot contains? Can we use the end_time as a marker to know that th snapshot contains all data modifications before that date?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-snapshots.html)

> Snapshotting process is executed in non-blocking fashion. All indexing
>   and searching operation can continue to be executed against the index
>   that is being snapshotted. However, a snapshot represents the
>   point-in-time view of the index at the moment when snapshot was
>   created, so no records that were added to the index after the snapshot
>   process was started will be present in the snapshot.

You will need to use start_time or start_time_in_millis.

Because snapshots are incremental, you can create first full snapshot and than one more snapshot right after the first one is finished, it will be almost instant.

One more question: why create functionality already implemented in elasticsearch? If you can run both clusters at the same time, you can merge both clusters, let them sync, switch write queries to new cluster and gradually disconnect old servers from merged cluster leaving only new ones.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion - thanks. I'm not sure how to force writes to only certain nodes. We are using the elasticsearch ruby gem for our incremental updates (keeping database in sync with ES index). I guess you mean to have new nodes join the cluster, replicate all the data over to the new nodes, then have the old nodes leave the cluster?

Comment: Exactly! Sorry for confusion. I have kept in mind two sets of links I would use to connect to ES cluster. One set is for old cluster, one is for new. And you have to use new links if you going to put old servers down.